# HTML5 Video autoplay/close

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, video, web

I'm wanting to open a video on the launch of a specific page visited by iPhone users, and then (when the video has finished) return back to the page. I'm also going to set a cookie at this point, so the video only loads first time (but I'm fine with that part).

I can find ways of linking straight through to an mp4, but I can't get back from there.
I've also come across the HTML5 video tags with Autoplay, but that doesn't seem to do what I want. Is there a jQuery solution? or a better HTML5 solution?

Answer (score 2):

To auto play you do the following

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

And to do something when it's finished

```
<script>

    //could easily be getElementById(NAME) also

    video.onended = function(e) {
      alert("The video finished");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason I can't post the line `video = getElementById('video');`

Comment: I also can't add `var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];`

Comment: Brill! Is there any way I can trigger the video to open as soon as the page is visited?

Comment: As detailed in Jbalsas's answer it appears that on iPad and iPhone (iOS) auto play and similar are disabled. So I would suggest just putting it full screen and assuming the user would press the placeholder button (https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/art/iphoneplaceholder.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but `autoplay` is disabled in IOS and most of mobile platforms.

For a video/audio to start playback, it is required user interaction. Autoplay is disabled to preserve bandwith and battery usage.

You can get more information about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1). Note that also javascript methods `video.play()` and `video.load()` are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The autoplay is disabled in IOS and most of mobile platforms.

"Note that also javascript methods video.play() and video.load() are disabled." 
This sentence is wrong, video.play() and video.load() are enabled for many mobile platforms. If you use WebView, please check WebSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true) on android, default value is false.

You can do that to instead autoplay.

```
<body onload="bodyLoad()">
<video id="video1" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
                                        <source src="video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                        </video>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1");

        function bodyLoad() {
                    setTimeout(playFunc, 10);
         }

        function playFunc() {
                    myVideo.play();
         }
</script>
```